# Regression Line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to plot a regression line on a scatterplot, based on my predicted data.

The problem is that I'm supposed to get a single line, but my plot has many lines connecting all points (see picture)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF483.png

After predicting CO2 emissions based on the other data, I plot the test engine size vs the actual data of the test(co2emissions) and I'm trying to plot the line on the engine size vs the predicted data of the test, but I can't.

Here is the code:

```
#import the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('FuelConsumptionCo2.csv')
cols = ['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELTYPE','FUELCONSUMPTION_CITY','FUELCONSUMPTION_HWY','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB','CO2EMISSIONS']

#create new dataset with colums neeeded
cdf = df[cols]
#dummies for the categorigal column fueltype
cdf = pd.get_dummies(cdf,'FUELTYPE')

#the features without the target column
selFeatures = list(cdf.columns.values)
del selFeatures[5]


#split the dataset for fitting
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(cdf[selFeatures], cdf['CO2EMISSIONS'], test_size=0.5)

#regression model
clfregr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

#train the model
clfregr.fit(X_train, Y_train)

#predict the values
train_pred = clfregr.predict(X_train)
test_pred = clfregr.predict(X_test)

#regression line for the predicted in test
plt.scatter(X_test.ENGINESIZE,Y_test,  color='gray')
plt.plot(X_test.ENGINESIZE, test_pred, color='red', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you have any sample data for the `FuelConsumptionC02.csv` ?

Comment: ah i got it from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sahilmishra0012/Datasets/master/FuelConsumption/FuelConsumption.csv

Comment: yeah sorry I didn't post a link for the dataset. But I guess it's used in many exercises so you found it quickly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 9 independent variables in the data. Therefore plotting by just one of them you will end up with duplicates per `ENGINESIZE` value. This does *not* result in a plottable function. When you attempt to draw a line it will zigzag among these multiple vertical points.

[image]

Notice when we do a `scatterplot` on the predictions we have many in one vertical line -corresponding to different values of the *other* eight independent variables than the one you are plotting on the `x-axis`:

```
 plt.scatter(X_test.ENGINESIZE, test_pred, color='yello') # , linewidth=1)
```

[image]

I will say - the `sklearn` `LinearRegression` class is quite difficult to use. I used `statsmodels` instead

```
plt.scatter(X_test.ENGINESIZE,Y_test,  color='gray')
import statsmodels.formula.api  as smf
y = Y_train
X = X_train
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : X.ENGINESIZE, 'y': y})
smod = smf.ols(formula ='y~ x', data=df)
result = smod.fit()
plt.plot(df['x'], result.predict(df['x']), color='red', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Then for extra credit

```
print(result.summary())
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are doing multiple linear regression. You should expect a straight line if Engine size is the ***only factor*** affecting CO2 emissions. But there are other factors too. If you have 2 independent variables, you will get a plane in 3D. If you have n variables, you should expect a linear shape in the n-dimensional metric space.

Comment: I thought that I could just plot based on the engine size from the same model but it apparently doesn't work like that. I can always make another model that only predicts based on the engine size and use that one to plot what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply this code to plot the regression model

```
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
x_train = np.asanyarray(df[['ENGINESIZE']])
y_train = np.asanyarray(df[['CO2EMISSIONS']])
model.fit (x_train, y_train)


plt.scatter(df['ENGINESIZE'], df["CO2EMISSIONS"], color='blue')
plt.plot(x_train, model.coef_[0][0]*x_train + model.intercept_[0], color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Oh the `model.coef_` is a 2-D array! why is that?

Comment: Yeah I had the same question

Comment: Also: why is it necessary to do `np.asanyarray()` ?  Is it just me or is `scikit-learn` like super hard to figure out the required input and output structures

Comment: @javadba just df[['ENGINESIZE']] worked for me. The only problem I had without the double [[ was when spliting the df, because it needs a df or a 2 dimension np array. I tried df['ENGINESIZE'] at first but it creates a series not a df so its 1D

Comment: coef_array of shape (n_features, ) or (n_targets, n_features)
Estimated coefficients for the linear regression problem. If multiple targets are passed during the fit (y 2D), this is a 2D array of shape (n_targets, n_features), while if only one target is passed, this is a 1D array of length n_features.https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Answer (score 2):

Try extracting the slope (m) and intercept (b) of the regression line from your `LinearRegression()` function and then use

`plt.plot(X_test.ENGINESIZE, m*X_test.ENGINESIZE + b, 'r', linewidth=1)`

or use seaborn's `lmplot` or `regplot` function.